# PageView.builder giving Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height error

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to flutter and I'm trying to learn how to create views. I tried to create a separate file of the view, or widget if that's what it's called in flutter, and just call it from the main.dart.

I have a separate widget containing this code

```
class PageEntryWidgetMain extends StatefulWidget {
  final PageViewEntryMain pageViewEntryMain;

  const PageEntryWidgetMain({Key key, this.pageViewEntryMain})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PageEntryWidgetMainState();
  }
}

class _PageEntryWidgetMainState extends State<PageEntryWidgetMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.pageViewEntryMain.title)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to show it by using a view pager with the following code

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                PageEntryWidgetMain(
                  pageViewEntryMain: pages[position],
                );
              },
              itemCount: pages.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

but it gives me the following errors

- Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
- Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.

I'm a little confused at what it's actually complaining of. I am able to display just one view, by replacing the PageView.builder with this code

```
PageEntryWidgetMain(pageViewEntryMain: pages[0])
```

So I believe that the separate widget, in itself, does not have a problem. It's probably about how I am trying to use the ViewPager that's giving me errors.

I have been searching for PageView implementations but I have not seen one that actually has a separate view to just call for displaying. I need to learn it this way so I would be able to separate the views instead of just writing it all in one file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`PageView` cannot be the direct child of `Column`. Change your column to add an `Expanded` between the two, as below:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: PageView.builder(),
    ),
  ]
)
```

To explain what's going on here, `Column` has an unbounded horizontal width, ie it'll keep expanding horizontally to take as much space as it's child needs. `PageView` (and any other horizontally scrolling widget) requires horizontal constraints for the scroll logic to work.

`Expanded` restricts the horizontal size of the `PageView` by taking up as much space as possible, which should solve the issue.

Comment: That's a really counter-intuitive behavior of a widget named `Expanded`

Answer (score 7):

You can use any Widget that has a **fixed height and width** to **wrap the PageView**.

For example, I use `Container()`:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100.0,
      child: PageView.builder(),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your widget tree is `SingleChildSrollView > Column > PageView`

Then surrounding PageView by Expanded or Flexible will cause `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded` error

You can use Container as wrapper instead.